# How to receive Twilio Autopilot data with PHP

Tags: php, json, twilio, twilio-autopilot

mates!

I have a PHP code that must receive some JSON (x-www-form-urlencoded) data from Twilio Autopilot redirect.

I am using the code below:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

The file_get_contents('php://input') is returnig data like below(Does not look like a JSON):

[image: It does not look like a JSON]

Does anyone can help me with this?

Comment: You might find [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) helpful.

Comment: What's the expected output? What have you tried to achieve whatever you need?

Comment: Thank you @NicoHaase , the anwer of "philnash" helped solve my problem. The result expected was a x-www-form-urlencoded and one of the data was a JSON. I used $_REQUEST["Memory"] and then json_decode at the result to accesses the data as object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is `x-www-form-urlencoded` data, which is definitely different from JSON data. `x-www-form-urlencoded` data is made up of key/value pairs that are separated by a `=` and each pair is separated by an `&`. For example: `CurrentTask=deliver_roomitems&CurrentInput=666`

In PHP you can parse this string with the [`parse_str` method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```php
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$parsed_data = parse_str($data, $result);
echo $result["CurrentTask"]; // => deliver_roomitems
```

When you receive incoming HTTP requests in PHP, data like this is usually parsed for you into the `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` variables. You should find you can also access the data by key in the relevant variables. e.g.

```php
echo $_REQUEST["CurrentTask"]; // => deliver_roomitems
```